# formatting date using moment.js

Tags: date, format, momentjs

Here is the fiddle for formatting using moment.js .

http://jsfiddle.net/lalithaexpert/Kznxf/

the problem is when the year is entered as `YY` instead of `YYYY` the result is shown as 00YY

for eg

`year :13` the year in result is `0013`

code

```
var now = moment("2-3-15","DD/MM/YYYY").format("MM/DD/YYYY");
$('#formatteddate').text(now);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use if you are sure that the date will always be YY.

```
 var now = moment("2-3-15","DD/MM/YY").format("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

Or check the date input and use the format depending on the date that you get:

```
var date = "2-3-15"; 
var dateArr = date.split("-");
var now = moment(date, dateArr[2].length == 2 ? "DD/MM/YY" : "DD/MM/YYYY").format("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

Not a very elegant solution, but somehow you need to narrow down the format of the input date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var now = moment("2-3-15","D-M-YY").format("MM/DD/YYYY");
$('#formatteddate').text(now);
```

js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Kznxf/3/